# output.filename impacted by output.chunkFilename?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I’m setting up an ASP.NET Core project, and would like my Razor templates to contain a reference to my entry chunks generated by webpack.

**What I want:**

I want to be able to reference my `main.js` and `runtime.js` from my Razor templates. I concluded that one way of doing it is to have Webpack always generate the same name for these files.

**What I did:**

Reading Webpack’s documentation, one can read this regarding the `output.chunkFilename` setting:

“[This option determines the name of non-entry chunk files.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-chunkfilename)”

Based on this assumption that using hashes in `chunkFilename` won’t affect my entry files, I used this configuration:

```
output: {
  path: outDir,
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  publicPath: 'dist/',
},
```

**What happened:**

Though what I’m getting is this:

```
wwwroot/dist
├───0.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
├───1.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
├───main.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
└───runtime.js
```

The `main` entrypoint is getting a hash, despite what the documentation says. Have I missed a step somewhere, misread the doc, or is there an issue of some kind between `filename` and `chunkFilename`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

OK, for future reference the `optimization.runtimeChunk: 'single'` option messes everything up and has every entrypoint bundle follow the `output.chunkFilename` setting.

So having these rules:

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
},

output: {
  path: outDir,
  filename: '[name].js',
  chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
  publicPath: 'dist/',
},
```

gives that structure:

```
wwwroot/dist
├───0.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
├───1.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
├───main.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
└───runtime.js
```

While removing the `optimization.runtimeChunk` setting gives that one:

```
wwwroot/dist
├───0.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
├───1.3b03e7acfc05abed54e5.js
└───main.js
```

In retrospect, since I don’t want my `main.js` to have a hash, it makes little sense to exctact the runtime into a separate file (the initial reason being that [the runtime code affects the `[contenthash]` part of the file name](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#extracting-boilerplate)), so it might be an intentional (although weird) behavior.

PS: No it is not. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6604

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I too was setting up for a .NET Core project with the exact same requirements - to reference my entry files, but still benefit from the chunking.